# Removing Element From Array of Arrays with Regex

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, node.js

I'm using regex to test certain elements in an array of arrays. If an inner array doesn't follow the desired format, I'd like to remove it from the main/outer array. The regex I'm using is working correctly. I am not sure why it isn't removing - can anyone advise or offer any edits to resolve this problem?

```
for (var i = arr.length-1; i>0; i--) {

      var a = /^\w+$/;
      var b = /^\w+$/;
      var c = /^\w+$/;  

    var first = a.test(arr[i][0]);
    var second = b.test(arr[i][1]);
    var third = c.test(arr[i][2]);

if ((!first) || (!second) || (!third)){
arr.splice(i,1);
}
```

Comment: can you create a jsfiddle with some test values?

Comment: have you tried the regex without trying to match start and end of line, i.e. ^ and $?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you cast `splice` method on an array, its `length` is updated immediately. Thus, in future iterations, you will probably jump over some of its members.

For example:

```
var arr = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g']

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  console.log(i, arr)
  if(i%2 === 0) {
    arr.splice(i, 1) // remove elements with even index
  }
}

console.log(arr)
```

It will output:

```
0 ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"]
1 ["b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"]
2 ["b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g"]
3 ["b", "c", "e", "f", "g"]
4 ["b", "c", "e", "f", "g"]

["b", "c", "e", "f"]
```

---

My suggestion is, do not modify the array itself if you still have to iterate through it. Use another variable to save it.

```
var arr = ['a','b','c','d','e','f','g']
var another = []

for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if(i%2) {
    another.push(arr[i]) // store elements with odd index
  }
}

console.log(another) // ["b", "d", "f"]
```

Or you could go with [**`Array.prototype.filter`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), which is much simpler:

```
arr.filter(function(el, i) {
  return i%2 // store elements with odd index
})
```

It also outputs:

```
["b", "d", "f"]
```

Comment: @djfkdjfkd39939 No, with `i < arr.length` you are getting the length in every iteration. If you cache the length like `var i = 0, l = arr.length` then `i < l`, you will probably encounter errors if you visit some index that was not existing yet.

Comment: @djfkdjfkd39939 updated my example so that you could see what happens to the array when you modify it in iterations.

Comment: @djfkdjfkd39939 It should work. The root cause you encountered has nothing to do with array nesting.

Comment: @djfkdjfkd39939 Yes. You were manipulating the array when iterating through it. Its length and members are changing every time `splice` was called. Read the first example in my answer.

Comment: In your example, the issue isn't really that the `length` keeps changing per se, things get skipped because when you remove the current item the "next" item has the same index as the current one did. The `for` statement will keep incrementing `i` every round even if you remove an item, which is what causes the skip. The code in the question goes over the array starting at the end and decrementing each round, it shouldn't suffer from this behavior since the lower indexes won't change when removing higher indexes.

Comment: @UselessCode my bad expression. The key point is elemets' **index** within the array are changed after splice, so they are skipped. length isn't really matter in this case.

Comment: Yeah, but the original code traverses the array from **end to start**, which avoids the kind of bug you are talking about. Removing index 3, thus making the item that was index 4 now 3, doesn't matter because the next item OPs code goes to is 2 which is unaffected by the change.

Answer (score 1):

Your code [seems to work](http://jsfiddle.net/UselessCode/3bgp8dzj/) to me. The code in your post was missing a `}` to close the `for` statement but that should have caused the script to fail to parse and not even run at all.

I do agree with Leo that it would probably be cleaner to rewrite it using [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) though.

The code in your question would look something like this as a filter:

```
arr = arr.filter(function (row) {
  return /^\w+$/.test(row[0]) && /^\w+$/.test(row[1]) && /^\w+$/.test(row[2]);
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UselessCode/d523gem8/)

I'm assuming it is 3 different regular expressions in your actual code, if they are all identical in your code you can save a little overhead by defining the RegExp literal once:

```
arr = arr.filter(function (row) {
  var rxIsWord = /^\w+$/;
  return rxIsWord.test(row[0]) && rxIsWord.test(row[1]) && rxIsWord.test(row[2]);
});
```